# Can not convert Base64 String and unGzip it properly

Tags: java, base64, gzip

I have Base64 String. I am trying to decode it, then decompress it.

```
String textToDecode = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAAEgAN//0JTQtdGC0LDQu9C40LfQuNGA0L7QstCw0L3QvdGL0LmRCuyiIAAAAA==\n";
byte[] data = Base64.decode(textToDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
String result = GzipUtil.decompress(data);
```

Code that I am using for decompression:

```
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
        string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    gis.close();
    is.close();
    return string.toString();
}
```

I should get this String:

```
Детализированный
```

Insteam of it, I am getting this String with question mark symbols:

```
Детализирован��ый
```

What is my mistake? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that when converting from bytes to String (internally Unicode)
the encoding is not given. And for a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8 one cannot take a fixed number of bytes (like 32) and then at the end have a valid sequence.

You experienced the loss of evidently a half sequence. Hence the encoding probably is UTF-8.

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
    baos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
}
gis.close();
return baos.toString("UTF-8"); // Or "Windows-1251" ...
```

The above does away with buffer boundary problems, and specifies the encoding, so the same code runs on different computers.

And mind:

- `new String(bytes, encoding)`
- `string.getBytes(encoding)`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the problem is here:

```
  string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead))
```

You are using the default character encoding to decode bytes into a Java String.  If the (current) default encoding is different to the encoding used when encoding the original characters to bytes (prior to compression, etc), then you could get bytes that don't decode correctly.  The decoder will then replace them with the decoder's replacement character; i.e. `'\uFFFD'` by default.

If this is the problem, then the solution is to find out what the correct character encoding is and use `String(byte[], int, int, Charset)` to create the `String`.

Comment: I identified that it was encoded by "UTF-8". Following your suggestion, I tried this `string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8"));` But it is not helping.

Comment: I suggest that you do a byte-by-byte comparison of the bytes before compression / base64 and after base64 / decompression.  And the lengths.  Also, ask yourself if that newline should be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you work only with streams you can avoid encoding problems, this few line of code should do the job well

```
 public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed))) {
                org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copy(gis, bos);
            }
            return bos.toString();
        }
    }
```